# Upgrade .netcore 2.1 to .net 6 - Linq Query Translation Error

Tags: c#, linq, .net-6.0

I have two two queries. The first one is like this.

```cs
var studentCourses = _context.StudentAcademicPathCourses
    .Include(x => x.Course)
    .Where(x => x.StudentAcademicPathId == studentAcademicPath.Id)
    .Select(apc => new
    {
        apc.AcademicPathSectionId,
        apc.CourseDerivation,

        Course = new
        {
            apc.Course.EctsCredits,
        },

        StudentCourseSection = apc.StudentCourseSection == null
                                || false == validStudentCourseSectionIds.Contains(apc.StudentCourseSectionId)
            ? null
            : new
            {
                apc.StudentCourseSection.Ects,
            },
    })
    .ToList();
```

The second one is

```cs
var result = _context.StudentAcademicPaths
    .Where(x => x.Id == studentAcademicPath.Id
                && x.TenantId == GetRequestUserTenantId())
    .Select(sap => new
    {
        AcademicPath = new
        {
            Sections = sap.AcademicPath.AcademicPathSections.Select(sec => new AcademicPathAPI_Section
            {
                CompletedECTS = studentCourses
                    .Where(x => x.AcademicPathSectionId == sec.Id
                        &&
                        (
                            x.CourseDerivation == AcademicPathCourseDerivation.Transferred
                            ||
                            (
                                x.StudentCourseSection != null
                                && true == x.StudentCourseSection.IsPassed
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    .Sum(x => x.Course.EctsCredits),

            })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Code)
            .ToList(),
        },
    }).First();
```

When the studentCourses finished, the result is running but CompletedECTS gives an error like this

> "The LINQ expression 'a => a.AcademicPathSectionId == EntityShaperExpression:
> EvolveAPI.Models.AcademicPathSection
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False
> .Id' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'." This error appeard after I upgrade framework to .netcore 2.1 to .net6

Comment: My guess : studentCourses is a list of objects loaded in memory, you can't use them as a parameter inside of your database linq query. Try to figure how to split better what happens on SQL side and what happens on c# side.

Comment: See "Restricted client evaluation": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/#restricted-client-evaluation